# A phrase that describes each member of a group

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

There are small units and each unit has its own clear mission. Each unit has only one mission. "Only one clear mission" is important and I need to emphasize it. I'd like to express the situation with a phrase and use it as a title of a presentation. I have made some candidate phrases. "Small units with a clear mission", "Small units with their own clear mission", "Small units with clear missions", etc. I think no one of them carries my intention properly. For example, "Small units with a clear mission" means that there is one mission and all units execute the mission. How can I express the situation with a phrase appropriately?

Comment: FWIW, using the word _cell_ instead of unit might help.

Answer (score 3):

In think the inclusion of the word *each* would solve your problem. NOAD says in its definition for each:

> **each** (*adj. & pronoun*) used to refer to every one of two or more people or things, regarded and identified separately

So, you could simply give your presentation this title:

> **Small Units – Each with a Clear Mission**

As an aside, I prefer using a dash in the title. [Dashes](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/dashterm.htm) are used “to set off a word or phrase after an independent clause.” In this case, the dash offers a concise way to emphasize that each unit has a clear mission, while preventing the title from becoming overly wordy. You could used a colon, too (except colons are sometimes used to indicate a subtitle of a book, so that might make "Each with a Clear Mission" look more like a subtitle, as opposed to part of the title).  A comma could work, also:

> Small Units, Each with a Clear Mission

but I prefer the dash.  Still, that’s a matter of preference.

Comment: Or *colon*. Small Units: Each with a clear mission.